# Convergence of $r_n$ = $a_n$ / $a_{n+1}$ where $a_n$ is Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

Let $a_n$ be the Fibonacci sequence defined by

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1} \ \ \text{with} \ \  a_0 = a_1 = 1 $$

Let $$r_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$$

I have already found two subsequences which are $\{r_{2k-1}\}$ bounded above by $2$ and  increasing (thus is convergent), and $\{r_{2k}\}$, bounded below by $1$ and decreasing (thus is convergent,too)

Besides, $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} r_{2k-1} = \ell_1 $$
I found that $l_1^2 - l_1 - 1 = 0$ from above equation.

However, i cannot find $l_2$ where $ \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} r_{2k} = \ell_2.$

Comment: The two subsequences approach the same limit.

Comment: what i posted here is exactly the same thing with what lecturer wrote on board and also she said prove that $l_2 = l_2^2 + l_2 +1$

Answer (score 0):

$$r_{2k}=\frac{a_{2k}}{a_{2k+1}}=\frac{a_{2k}}{a_{2k}+a_{2k-1}}=\frac1{1+r_{2k-1}}.$$

Then

$$l_2=\frac1{1+l_1}.$$